# How to handle HTML content in Windows 8 Metro App

Tags: html, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I'm designing a Windows 8 Reader App, and I have to use a control to show the HTML content, which is fetched from some website feeds. Cause those HTML content may contains images or some  other formatted text, now I'm using a richtextblock to show the HTML content, but it costs a lot of time to parse the HTML content.

So I'm wondering if there is any controls that can handle the HTML content except the WebView.

Thanks.

Updated:
The reason I can't use WebView is that I need to implement pagination, like the image belowed:

[image]

Comment: What's wrong with the WebView control?

Comment: So you are not using HTML to develop this app?

Answer (score 4):

As JP Alioto mentioned you should use the [WebView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview) control.

You can use the [NavigateToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.navigatetostring) method to load the HTML. Or use [Navigate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.navigate) to request a URI.

There are issues however with using the WebView control, specifically it is rendered differently and is not a standard control, this means things like your app bar or settings pane will not render on top of the WebView, there is a workaround by using the [WebViewBrush](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webviewbrush) to "paint" the WebView to standard control such as a rectangle when needed.

Answer (score 1):

Also you can make a screenshot of the webpage you want to display. But to make a screenshot of webpage it's also not easy to do, but I offer you to make it with some special sites wich are created to take screenshot of other websites. Then you can download an image this sites return and open and display it in your windows 8 app. I show You some example how to I did that:

```
 StorageFolder screens = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.CreateFolderAsync(@"Screens\" + folderName, CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);
 var downloader = new BackgroundDownloader();
 IStorageFile file = await screens.CreateFileAsync(fname, CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);
 string my_uri = "http://api.snapito.com/web/e3c351d5994134eb1aea855ce78e296c3292d48a/lc/" + url + "?type=jpeg";
 DownloadOperation download = downloader.CreateDownload(new System.Uri(my_uri), file);
 await download.StartAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there are only two options but none of them are really good:

- Use WebView and transform your HTML with CSS and other techniques to look native. Use the `ScriptNotify` and `NavigationStarting` and other events to navigate to another page. In W8.1 the WebView is much better (eg. treated as regular control not floating over all other controls,...)
- Parse your HTML and generate native elements. I started such an implementation and created a XAML control to display HTML with native controls (see https://mytoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=HtmlTextBlock). However if you have complex HTML (eg iframes, etc.) this may not work and you have no other choice than to use the WebView control.

Comment: Thanks, I will go through it... & get back to you soon.

Comment: Maybe you have to change the items panel of the FixedHtmlTextBlock ItemsControl to have the correct Win8 text flow...